# MySQL String Position and Substring sort

Tags: mysql

Example data to sort:

> xy3abc
>   y3bbc
>   z3bd

Sort order must be abc, bbc, bd regardless of what is before the numeral.

I tried:

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  LEAST(
    if (Locate('0',fcccall) >0,Locate('0',fcccall),99),
    if (Locate('1',fcccall) >0,Locate('1',fcccall),99),
    if (Locate('2',fcccall) >0,Locate('2',fcccall),99),
    if (Locate('3',fcccall) >0,Locate('3',fcccall),99),
    if (Locate('4',fcccall) >0,Locate('4',fcccall),99),
    if (Locate('5',fcccall) >0,Locate('5',fcccall),99),
    if (Locate('6',fcccall) >0,Locate('6',fcccall),99),
    if (Locate('7',fcccall) >0,Locate('7',fcccall),99),
    if (Locate('8',fcccall) >0,Locate('8',fcccall),99),
    if (Locate('9',fcccall) >0,Locate('9',fcccall),99)
  ) as locationPos,
  SUBSTRING(fcccall,locationPos,3) as fccsuffix
FROM memberlist
ORDER BY locationPos, fccsuffix
```

but `locationPos` gives me an error on the substring function call

Comment: Did you try nested query?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?  Sample data and desired results would be helpful.

Comment: Why are you ordering by locationPos first before fccsuffix? This would give you (bbc, bd, abc).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to reference that expression by its alias `locationPos`, within another expression in the same `SELECT` list.

Replicating the entire expression would be the SQL way to do it. (Yes, it is ugly repeating that entire expression.)

Another (less performant) approach is to use your query (minus the `fccsuffix` expression) as an inline view. The outer query can reference the assigned `locationPos` alias as a column name.

As a simple example:

```
SELECT v.locationPos
  FROM ( SELECT 'my really big expression' AS locationPos
           FROM ...
       ) v
```

This approach of using an inline view ("derived table") can have some serious performance implications with large sets.

But for raw performance, repeating the expression is the way to go:

```
SELECT *
     , LEAST(
        if (Locate('0',fcccall) >0,Locate('0',fcccall),99),
        if (Locate('1',fcccall) >0,Locate('1',fcccall),99),
        if (Locate('2',fcccall) >0,Locate('2',fcccall),99),
        if (Locate('3',fcccall) >0,Locate('3',fcccall),99),
        if (Locate('4',fcccall) >0,Locate('4',fcccall),99),
        if (Locate('5',fcccall) >0,Locate('5',fcccall),99),
        if (Locate('6',fcccall) >0,Locate('6',fcccall),99),
        if (Locate('7',fcccall) >0,Locate('7',fcccall),99),
        if (Locate('8',fcccall) >0,Locate('8',fcccall),99),
        if (Locate('9',fcccall) >0,Locate('9',fcccall),99)
       ) AS locationPos
     , SUBSTRING(fcccall
       , LEAST(
          if (Locate('0',fcccall) >0,Locate('0',fcccall),99),
          if (Locate('1',fcccall) >0,Locate('1',fcccall),99),
          if (Locate('2',fcccall) >0,Locate('2',fcccall),99),
          if (Locate('3',fcccall) >0,Locate('3',fcccall),99),
          if (Locate('4',fcccall) >0,Locate('4',fcccall),99),
          if (Locate('5',fcccall) >0,Locate('5',fcccall),99),
          if (Locate('6',fcccall) >0,Locate('6',fcccall),99),
          if (Locate('7',fcccall) >0,Locate('7',fcccall),99),
          if (Locate('8',fcccall) >0,Locate('8',fcccall),99),
          if (Locate('9',fcccall) >0,Locate('9',fcccall),99)
         ),3
       ) AS fccsuffix
  FROM memberlist
 ORDER BY locationPos, fccsuffix
```

Unfortunately, with MySQL, it's not possible to reference the result of the `locationPos` column within an expression in the *same* SELECT list.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it has to be nested like that. Such a shame. I suppose it gives argument to creating a function to do this and I have only 100 records or so and understand the performance hit.

Comment: (Other databases support what you are looking for. Teradata SQL lets us use `NAMED` in place of `AS`, and then we *can* reference the alias in other expressions. (I think under the covers Teradata expands out the reference to the `NAMED` alias, as if we had typed out that whole expression again, like in my example of replicating the expression.)

Comment: Fortunately, you *can* reference the expressions by their alias in the `ORDER BY` clause. How ugly would that be, having to repeat the expressions *again*. With only 100 rows, the performance of the inline view isn't likely to be an issue. Where it becomes a concern is very large sets. (It gets expensive to materialize a huge "derived table", and then turn around and run a query against it, and then perform a sort operation.) Writing a function is an option, but for raw performance, you can't beat the native builtin functions. With only 100 rows, you won't notice a difference.

Comment: For the current record set the server can handle it in less than 0.2 milliseconds. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For only one numeral I like:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM memberlist
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(fcccall, 
           LOCATE('0',fcccall)+
           LOCATE('1',fcccall)+
           LOCATE('2',fcccall)+
           LOCATE('3',fcccall)+
           LOCATE('4',fcccall)+
           LOCATE('5',fcccall)+
           LOCATE('6',fcccall)+
           LOCATE('7',fcccall)+
           LOCATE('8',fcccall)+
           LOCATE('9',fcccall),3)
```

But the sensible approach is not to store two separate bits of information in one field.